# Getting PhantomJS to work with a java application

Tags: java, phantomjs

I am testing around with PhantomJS a bit.

But I am not sure how to make it work with a java application, th examples I have found are mostly just against files or sites.

So this is what I have now.

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();

 address = "http://localhost:8080/logon.do";       

page.open(address, function(status) {
    wait(5000);
      if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
      phantom.exit();

});


function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

Now I know this wait is ugly but it is not important right now.
The server is running and if I go to the url I get a log in page.
I was expecting this log in page to be the output of console.log(ua);
Instead I get the output: 
<-html><-head><-/head><-body><-/body><-/html>

What am I missing?

Comment: That looks like Javascript and not like Java.

Answer (score 0):

OK this turned out to be very secific for our application so lets close this.
Sascha, yes it is the script called by phantomjs which in turn